# Django + Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to use jquery with my django application and it is having no effect. I have installed jquery using

```
pip install django-staticfiles-jquery
```

This successfully installed. I then added jquery to my INSTALLED_APPS. In my project, I have

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'twitterclone/styletwo.css' %}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'twitterclone/scriptwo.j' %}"></script>
</head>
```

For some reason, this successfully loads and uses the css file, but does not use the jquery file. Can anyone help? I have seen others say that using google-hosted servers (AJAX?) is an alternative, but I would rather not have to do so.

Comment: figured it out; just had to add 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
to get the jquery library

Answer (score 3):

Just something I noticed, on your script src tag, you might have forgotten an 's', since most javascript files end with ".js"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'twitterclone/scriptwo.j' %}"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'twitterclone/scriptwo.js' %}"></script>
```